# Maximal compact subgroups of p-adic orthogonal groups

Tags: reference-request, reductive-groups, p-adic-groups

Let F be a non-archimedean local field, and G be split orthogonal groups of odd degrees $\geq$ 3.

In this setting, my question is;
Is there explicit descriptions of maximal compact subgroups of G?

I am especially interested in the case that the residue field of F has characteristic 2.

Any reference or comments, or answers for this question or for general cases (e.g. classical p-adic groups) would be appreciated.

Comment: As with any reductive $p$-adic group, these are the stabilisers of points in the extended building.  What counts as an explicit answer?  If you're interested, Tits's Corvallis article discusses the quasi-split but non-split case.

Comment: Did you check :  Schémas en groupes et immeubles des groupes classiques sur un corps local. II : groupes unitaires, Bruhat, F. ; Tits, J., Bulletin de la Société Mathématique de France, Tome 115 (1987) , pp. 141-195 ?  They give models for the buildings of classical groups in any characteristic.

Comment: Thank you all. I try them.